# What do I need to change for this function to calculate the corrrect average?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I'm very new to Java, and I'm trying to create a class `Average` whose object calculates the average of a number of integers (objects of another class Integers) that can be added to it via the `addNumber` method first.

I can see that the correct numbers are added to the object and that the counter works correctly too, but I just can't seem to figure out how to calculate the sum of the `ArrayList` so that I can then calculate the average of these numbers by dividing its sum by my counter.

For this line here, I keep getting the error message that Integer cannot be converted to int:

```
for (int i : variables)
```

Which makes sense, but so far none of the ways I tried to convert it to one seems to work. I actually copied that one line of code from here (https://coderanch.com/t/673671/java/correctly-Sum-contents-ArrayList-Integer) but for me that really doesn't seem to work. Do I need to import anything besides `import java.util.*;` ?

```
public class Average
{
    // Ints given by the user
    private ArrayList<Integer> variables;
    private int count = 0;
    private int sum;
    
    // Resulting average
    private int average;
   

    /**
     * When creating object, takes numbers from class Integer
     */
    public Average()
    {
        variables = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    /**
     * Add variables to calculate averages from
     */
    
    public void addNumber(Integer newNumber)
    {
        variables.add(newNumber);
        count ++;      
    }
    /**
     * Method to calculate the average of the given variables
     */
    
    public int calcAverage(ArrayList<Integer> variables)
    {
        for (int i : variables)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
        average = sum / count;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you shared here.

First, from an API perspective, why would `calcAverage` take an `ArrayList<Inetger>` as a parameter if the class has the `variables` data member? Such a method should either be `static` or take no argument and calculate the average of the member.

Second, from a coding perspective, it returns the `sum` before assigning the value to the average, making the line `average = sum / count` unreachable code, and causing a compilation error.

Third, from a mathematical perspective, since `sum` and `count` are `int`s, their division will be performed as [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), giving you the wrong result in most cases.

Finally, the `Average` class doesn't have any access methods to retrieve the numbers added to it, or modification methods to modify this list other than adding numbers to it. Taking this API under consideration, it may be redundant to hold a list of numbers. Instead, you could just hold the `sum` and `count` of the numbers being added, and return their average on demand:

```java
public class Average {
    private int count = 0;
    private int sum = 0;
    
    /**
     * Add variables to calculate averages from
     */
    public void addNumber(int newNumber) {
        sum += newNumber;
        count++;
    }

    /**
     * Method to calculate the average of the given variables
     */
    public double calcAverage() {
        return ((double) sum) / count;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Also using Java 8 you can do it in much simpler way as below:
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,2,3,1,5);

    Double average = intList.stream().mapToInt(val -> val).average().orElse(0.0);

Comment: Thanks so much Mureinik!
Concerning the mathematical part I completely agree. It's just that the assignment I was working on for some reason only wants integers, and so I stuck with that, but ordinarily, I agree that a float value would've yielded more useful results :)

The rest I will now look at in more detail! Thanks for taking the time to reply with so much detail :)

Comment: Okay so yes the code makes sense, and it works perfectly. But I would have still liked to understand how I could theoretically calculate the sum of an ArrayList. 

I get that in this particular case it isn't really needed, but how could I give the class access methods to retrieve or modify the numbers?